# jquery mobile background scrolls with listview

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a listview like so -

```
<ul id="mylist" data-role="listview"  data-inset="true" > </ul>
```

I also have a background image set to the page id like this -

```
#spots {
    background: transparent url('images/background.png') no-repeat; 
    background-position:center center !important;
    background-size:cover;  
}
```

When I populate the listview with 20+ rows the background becomes distorted and enlarged, also when I scroll down the background stays at the top.

is there any way to make the background completely static and stay its set dimensions and also make it so just the listview scrolls?

Comment: evreything has a background, the page the listview, the items hence the reason its scrolling, so one way is to use the html tag for the background and fix it and have the page and the listview trasparent https://jsfiddle.net/vot8pz9x/

Comment: thanks, just what i needed :)